# Property is true for input field but false for select field

Tags: angular

I would like to check whether any of my fields have been changed. If so, tell my function that there are changes.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #gender (selectionChange)="_update('personal', 'gender', gender.value)" formControlName="gender">
    <mat-option value="f">Female</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="m">Male</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input #firstName (blur)="_update('personal', 'firstName', firstName.value)" formControlName="firstName" type="text" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
private valueChanged = false;

ngOnInit() {
  Object.keys(this.profileFormGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.profileFormGroup.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      if (!this.profileFormGroup.get(key).pristine) {
        this.valueChanged = true;
      }
    });
  });
}

private _update(tableName: string, columnName: string, theValue: any) {
  if (this.valueChanged) {
    console.log('Value has changed!');
  }
}
```

The problem is, my function `_update()` returns *Value has changed* on the first time when I change the text of the input field (that's how it should be). But when I change the value of the select field, only after the second change it outputs *Value has changed* but the first time will be ignored, since `this.valueChanged` is still *false*.

Why does it work for my input field but not for my select field?

Comment: can you share a stackblitz which recreates this issue, that way it will be a lot easier to help

Comment: Feel free to add related code! like formGroup Structure etc.

Comment: Seems fine to me! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfkz6s

Comment: Note that you're making it much harder than necessary. The formGroup itself has pristine/dirty flags. It becomes dirty as soon as one of its controls becomes dirty. But being dirty doesn't imply that a value changed. If you type 'A' then backspace in an input, the value didn't change, but the field is still dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check any of the form fields have been changed:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => console.log('Form values-',formValue));
```

implement method -

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.profileFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => {
    console.log('Called new',formValue);
  });
  //  Object.keys(this.profileFormGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
  //   this.profileFormGroup.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
  //     console.log('Called')
  //     if (!this.profileFormGroup.get(key).pristine) {
  //       this.valueChanged = true;
  //     }
  //   });
  // });  
}

private _update(tableName: string, columnName: string, theValue: any) {
  if (this.valueChanged) {
    console.log('Value has changed!');
}
```

Comment: That seems to work fine at the beginning but if I change the value of the input field first and then change the value of the select field, `this.valueChanged` is true for the input field but false for the select field.

Comment: I have tried it with `this.valueChanged = false; this.profileFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();` at the end of my function and now it works great.